# Should I downgrade VisualStudio for Box2D?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, box2d

The latest version of Box2D is made for VS2013, while my currently version of VS is 2015, while it should not cause any trouble on simpler code...It does.
I've been dealing with a lot of errors (I fixed most of them) but still it doesn't seem to work at its potential.
While VS2015 is not a necessity for me I would simply downgrade it, but I'm concerned if that is going to do any good on Box2D.

My question is : 
Should I deal with Box2D in VS2015 or should I downgrade that to 2013.

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of errors are you seeing with VS2015? I wouldn't expect any trouble either

Comment: At first, warnings as error mainly "C2220" warning, after i turned warnings off and ran it, the app wouldn't start I don't quite remember the reason but it was something with box2d.lib, I changed the Startup file and it started, but it still wouldn't work after about 4 second it threw me an exception so here I am

Comment: I would try compiling Box2D from source using CMake to generate a Visual Studio 14 2015 project.

Comment: Oh, as ready-compiled library it might have issues with different C++ library versions or something. Compiling it yourself might allow having a VS2015 version, but can't say for sure.

Comment: For now I will go with an older version until I get the hang out of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wasn't 100% sure, downgrading really fixed all the errors I had, so I would recommend if someone has some minor errors which include :

1.Warnings, lots of them

2.Any possible error which isn't answered anywhere

3.Exceptions

To downgrade to the specified version